# Need help building Java project in VsCode

Tags: visual-studio-code, javafx, build

I wrote a small program in VsCode using JavaFX. Using VsCode, I export to a jar file and the program won't run. I run `java -verbose -jar jar-file` and the only error is `Error: JavaFX runtime components are missing, and are required to run this application`. When I list the contents of the jar, it contains a ton of javafx classes.

I also tried creating an image using jlink, but I could not locate a .bat file. I could use some help in learning what I am doing wrong.